# findViewById giving me an issue when setting it outside context

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am calling my `Main.java` from `AndroidManifest.xml` in the `onCreate` method of `Main.java` file I create a new instance of `MainView.java` and send over `Context`. In `MainView.java` I have a method called `buildView` that returns a `LinearLayout`. In the `LinearLayout` I am creating a `Spinner` and a `Button`. I gave the `Spinner` a `.setId(1)`. In the `Button` I am adding a `setOnClickListener`. In the `onClick` method I am referencing the `Spinner` using `findViewById(1)`. Here is where I am getting an error. Eclipse is asking me to create a method called `findViewById`.

I copied the code I had in my Main `onCreate` method and moved it into `MainView.java` so I am able to decide what View I want to load up at the start. The idea is to have `FooView.java`, `BlahView.java` so when the applications starts it will decide what ?View.java to load.

Here is code in `MainView.java`

```
    public LinearLayout buildView(){
    this.datasource = new LocationDataSource(context);
    this.datasource.open();

    LinearLayout llmain = new LinearLayout(context);
    llmain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    llmain.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    LinearLayout llcore = new LinearLayout(context);
    llcore.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    llcore.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(600,-2));

    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    String tx = "Select Location";
    tv.setText(tx);
    tv.setPadding(0, 25, 0, 0);
    llcore.addView(tv);

    LinearLayout llTemp = new LinearLayout(context);
    llTemp.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    llTemp.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(600,-2));
    llTemp.setPadding(0, 15, 0, 0);
    Spinner s = new Spinner(context);
    s.setId(1);
    s.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(450,80));
    final List<SpinnerObject> list = this.datasource.getLocation();
    final ArrayAdapter<SpinnerObject> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<SpinnerObject>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);
    llTemp.addView(s);

    Button b = new Button(context);
    b.setText("Select");
    b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(150,80));
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //need help here
            //need help here
            //need help here
            //need help here
            //need help here


            Spinner spin = (Spinner)findViewById(1);
            //String str = Integer.toString(( (SpinnerObject) spin.getSelectedItem () ).getId () );

        /*  if(spin.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0){
                Messages message = new Messages(context);
                message.alert("ERROR", "Selecting a location is required!");
            }else{
                //loadVehicle();
            }*/
        }

    });
    llTemp.addView(b);      
    llcore.addView(llTemp);

    llmain.addView(llcore);
    return llmain;
}
```

Comment: Try out as `Spinner spin=s.getId();` in your click listener.

Comment: You don't need to findviewbyid. In onclick you can just getid of the spinner and handle that.

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? Why not just create the `layout` files and go to the appropriate `Activity` depending on your `SharedPref` value? It would be much simpler that way.

Comment: -1 it is not possible to answer because you did not tell us nothing about class where `buildView` method came from... **now let me use my magic orb:** i'm pretty sure that **it is not a class which extends** `Activity` or `View` so it doesn't have findViewById method ... you can make `llmain` final and then use llmain.findViewById ...

Comment: @Selvin you were totally correct with your **magic orb** I create `LinearLayout` in `Main.java` that extends `Activity` and send it over to `MainView.java` and was able to use `findViewById`. If you want to put this as your answer I will mark it as correct. My other issue is being able to call the method `loadVehicle();` from the `onClick` if I am explaining this write

Comment: I am only two weeks into learning java so kind of clouded in a lot of areas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 Spinner spin = (Spinner)context.findViewById(1);
```

or get a final reference to your Spiner before on click and reuse it as is

```
final tempSpinner = s;
Button b = new Button(context);
b.setText("Select");
b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(150,80));
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    //reuse tempSpinner

   }
```

Comment: As said by codeMagic in the comments you may not need to create the view programmaticaly. create a layout in res/layout/ called main.xml and use setContentView(R.layout.main)

Comment: I am creating the View dynamically not using `.xml` files

Comment: It can be usefull in some case I'm doing so in an application I'm working on, did you try my solution ?

Comment: @Selvin had the solution i needed